# Error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

hello i have this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/project/templates/yoo_balance/layouts/com_content/article/default.php on line 191

here is the code : http://paste2.org/hMZ6z0dF

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Parts of your code are not interpreted as PHP code since they're not in `<?php` context. Since some parts are missing, PHP will throw that error. The file should look like this: http://paste2.org/bDFEs5Ek

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself; if paste2.org dies, this question is useless.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a dumping site for code that spills errors on you. But you can ask understanding questions for PHP error messages, but then you need to explain your own understanding as well.

Comment: And why do you use PHP opening and closing tags that many times? That's completely unnecessary and in this case the cause of your error.

Comment: Thank you Amal Murali for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on 143rd line,.

You are closing `php` 2 times

- 143rd line and
- 180th line

so just remove `?>` from 143rd line

Answer (score 0):

on line 132 you are closing the php code with '?>'. And then you continue without opening another `'<?php'` .remove that line.

```
   ?>

    if (isset($images->image_fulltext) and !empty($images->image_fulltext)) {
```

and because you have MANY unnecessary opening and closings of php sections, you must have many more similar errors...